# In an Android app, how to ignore the default app preferences and force users to choose apps?

Tags: java, android

When I send user to open a link in a browser, can I force the user to select from their available browsers, without using their default browser?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @chrylis because the link won't renter on android default browser (on older android versions), so i want to  have the option to select other browsers like chrome,etc.. if they have default browser as android browser.

Comment: @kisa What do you think is the default browser?  Hint, its different for every OEM and version, not to mention the user could have overidden it.  And I suggest you fix your link if it isn't rendering.

Comment: Not to mention that the user may not have any other browsers installed. Fixing the page is definitely the best path.

Comment: Its not possible to change it, that's why im looking for a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

String title = "Select a browser";
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Comment: @kisa Is it possible to open content beyond this link in your app without browser? If yes, may be better trying use deep link or instant app?

Comment: I think this does not work expectedly when [Settings] > [Apps & Notifications] > [Default Apps] is set.